# Better way of writing this (javascript ternary statement/gulp 4)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp

```
function clean(done) {
  ...
}    

function serve(done) {
  ...
}


function empty(done) {
  done();
}

const dev = gulp.series(
  clean,
  build ? empty : serve,
  ...
);
```

Within a Gulp 4 series, check for build condition then execute serve task if not true.

Comment: Looks quite good. What should be better?

Comment: Questions like this one should be asked over on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Just felt a bit unnecessary writing an empty function to negate the 'if' part of the ternary. Thought there might be a cleaner way testing for the negative of a condition within a gulp.series. Okay @hon2a, noted for the future.

Comment: `const tasks = [ clean ]; if (build) tasks.push(serve); /* ... */ gulp.series(...tasks);`